# How to store value inside runtime?

Tags: oracles, acurast

I have decoded price from acurast, now I want to store the price in chain and access it. How can this be done?

```
pub struct OnAcurastFulfillment;
impl pallet_acurast_fulfillment_receiver::traits::OnFulfillment<Runtime> for OnAcurastFulfillment {
    fn on_fulfillment(
        _from: <Runtime as frame_system::Config>::AccountId,
        _fulfillment: Fulfillment,
    ) -> DispatchResultWithInfo<PostDispatchInfo> {
        // fulfillment.payload contains the bytes processed by the script
        
        let price: u128 =
            parity_scale_codec::decode_from_bytes(_fulfillment.payload.into()).unwrap_or_default();

        Ok(().into())
    }
}
```

[project github link](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/tanssi/blob/1356707bc3a248c00340ec552dcef4b0d1517ff4/container-chains/templates/simple/runtime/src/lib.rs#L971)

[tutorial I follow](https://docs.acurast.com/integrations/substrate/#substrate-integration-1)

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you want to put this value into `pallet_price::Price` at runtime level.

```rs
// if it is a storage value
<pallet_price::Price<Runtime>>::put(price);

// if it is a storage map
// just an example here, so I use `(price, ())`
<pallet_price::Price<Runtime>>::insert(price, ());
```